# use flutter json annotation one model into an other model

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, bloc, nsjsonserialization, json-annotation

i have two models one is user model and other is milestone model. from the api i will ge a list of milestones like this with other user's data
`user: { first_name: "Foo", last_name: "Bar", "milestones": [ { "id": 1, "user_id": 1, "title": "first mile", "start_date": 1704455618, "end_date": 1704455618, "notified": 0 } ] }`

so first i createda milestone model like this

// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'milestone.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class MileStone {
  int? id;
  int? user_id;
  String? title;
  bool? notified;
  @JsonKey(fromJson: _unixToDateTime)
  DateTime? start_date;
  @JsonKey(fromJson: _unixToDateTime)
  DateTime? end_date;
  MileStone({
    this.id,
    this.user_id,
    this.title,
    this.notified,
    this.start_date,
    this.end_date

  });

  factory MileStone.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$MileStoneFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MileStoneToJson(this);

  static DateTime? _unixToDateTime(dynamic value) => value == null ? null :
  (value is int) ? DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(value * 1000, isUtc: true) :  (value is String) ? DateTime.parse(value) :value;
}
```

and then i used it in my user model like this

```
class User {
  String first_name;
  String? last_name;
  @JsonKey(name: 'milestones',fromJson: _milestonesList)
  List<MileStone>? milestones;

  User({
    required this.first_name,
    this.last_name,
    this.milestones,

  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);

  static List<MileStone>? _milestonesList(List<dynamic>? list) =>
      list?.map((dynamic item) => MileStone.fromJson(item as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList();

}
```

but i am getting null wheneven i do

`if(state is UserLoggedIn){ print(state.user.milestones); }`

what i am doing wrong?

i am trying to save midlestone data using milestone model in user's model.

Comment: Why do you need custom fromJson for the `milestones` property? I think json_serializable should handle list automatically.

Comment: even if i do it like this 
 List<dynamic>? milestones;
i still get null 
i am new to flutter so i assumed maybe this is a good way handle it like this

Comment: plus i aslo need to convert the unix timestamp in the milestones to date time so it does look like a good idea to use it like that

Comment: i think this way i will get more power to control what i need to do witht the properties inside the milestone